# SQL-split a column and add the value to another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, sql-server-2016

I have a table that looks like this. It has thousands of rows

```
Name       Address  LName
Mike_Cole  NewYork  Null
```

I want to split the Name and add the LastName to the column `LName`.

My table should look like:

```
Name       Address  LName
Mike_Cole  NewYork  Cole
```

Comment: what database system are you using? As this will affect the awnser

Comment: I am using SQL 2016

Comment: Is it always `First_Last`, or can there be multiple underscores? If there can, how should those be handled?

Comment: There can be multiple underscores. I am fine with just putting everything after the first underscore in the column LName.

Comment: try this select Name,Address,SUBSTRING(Name,CHARINDEX('_', Name),LEN(Name)) as Lname from Table

Comment: try this if you want to update records
update t set Lname = SUBSTRING(Name,CHARINDEX('_', Name),LEN(Name))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want everything after the first underscore, you can do:

```
update t
    set LName = substring(name, charindex('_', name + '_') + 1, len(name);
```

Comment: Gordon, thanks for the quick answer. Much appreciated.

Comment: If I want anything to the left of the _ character, what should be the command? I am trying update Contact
set FName= (left(SupportTopic, charindex('\', SupportTopic)-1))

Comment: it complains "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function." Without the -1, it works

Comment: I am trying update Contact set FName= (left(name, charindex('\', name)-1))

Comment: @user2469235 . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you have asked.  It is unfair to change the question in comments.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I am sorry. I did not realize that I was just updating the comments.

Answer (score 0):

if is sql server  you could use

```
  select name, addres RIGHT(name,LEN(name)-CHARINDEX('_',name)) lname
  from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table_name SET  LName = RIGHT(Name,LEN(Name) - CHARINDEX('_', Name))
```

However, this assumes there is only 1 underscore in the name!

This is a better solution:

```
 UPDATE table_name SET  LName = RIGHT(Name,CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(Name)) - 1)
```

Also to get the First Name:

```
 UPDATE table_name SET  FName = LEFT(Name,CHARINDEX('_', Name) - 1)
```

Comment: When I add the -1 , it gives error "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function."

Comment: When trying to extract the firstName using the statement 
 UPDATE table_name SET  FName = LEFT(Name,CHARINDEX('_', Name) - 1),  it gives error "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function."

Comment: Do you have data without an _ character?

Comment: Hi Andrew, I realized that I do have strings that does not have _ character. Is it possible to select the complete value for such rows?